# how to set the ItemsSource of a listview in a listview, using a recursive object as main datasource?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

### *SOLVED by a kind soul who made me realise I need to debug more thouroughly.* The code I put forward here actually works.

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for days, it first appeared to be easy but I haven't been able to make it work.

I have an object which contains a collection of itself:

```
public class Car: ViewModelBase 
{ 
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { Set(ref _name, value); } }

    private ObservableCollection<Car> _carCollection = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
    public ObservableCollection<Car> CarCollection { get { return _carCollection; } set { Set(ref _carCollection, value); } }
}
```

In my ViewModel I define an object instance :

```
public class RecipesViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private Car _car; 
    public Car Car  { get { return _car; } set { Set(ref _car, value); } }

    //User populates the name prop and the list within car (level 1 data), 
   //and adds a number of objects to the list within the level 1 list  (level 2 data)
}
```

In the view/XAML I set up a list with Itemtemplate, and a datasource:

```
<Page
x:Class="CarProject.Views.CarPage"
DataContext="{Binding CarViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
...
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.Car.CarCollection, Mode=OneWay}" 
                              x:Key="CarListSource" 
                              IsSourceGrouped="False"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
<ListView x:Name="CarList"
          ItemsSource ="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecipeSingleAromaListSource}, Mode=OneWay}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Car" x:Name="CarItem" >
               <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                  <ListView x:Name="Level2Sublist"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CarCollection"}>
                       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
               </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
 </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I have tried many permutations of RelativeSource and ItemsSource definitions for "Level2SubList", but I can't seem to reference to the level2 car collection.
The "Level2SubList" stays blank no matter what I do.

I've been searching the web and havent found a similar usecase. Maybe I need a lesson in using Google, because I can't be the only one having tried this :)

Thanks!

P.S.
The class and XAML list contain a bunch of other properties, I simplified it for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `DataTemplate` has no `x:DataType` attribute, which is required if you are using `x:Bind`:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Car">
   ...
</DataTemplate>
```

And then, to actually show the `Name` of the car, you are using `Name` property of `TextBlock`, but that actually sets the XAML Name. You need the `Text` property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
```

### Update

Apart from these issues the code works for me. Try the following in a blank UWP project (mine's name is `App3`):

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="CarList"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Car.CarCollection}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Car" x:Name="CarItem" >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                        <ListView x:Name="Level2Sublist"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CarCollection}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App3
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


        public Car Car { get; } = new Car()
        {
            CarCollection = new ObservableCollection<Car>()
            {
                new Car(){Name = "A", CarCollection = new ObservableCollection<Car>(){ new Car(){Name="A1"}, new Car(){Name="A2" } } },
                new Car(){Name = "B", CarCollection = new ObservableCollection<Car>(){ new Car(){Name="B1"}, new Car(){Name="B2" }, new Car(){Name="B3" } }}
            }
        };
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Car> CarCollection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can see the app displays even the nested list:

[image: App]

Comment: Hi Martin, Yes thanks for pointing that out. I made mistakes writing it here as I was still sleepy. I don't have these mistakes in Visual Studio.
I did set a datatype to the inner listviews DataTemplate. I was playing around with "Binding" and "x:Bind" to see if it was compile related.
"Name" should indeed be "Text", I have changed it in my post.
The issue remains though. The "Name" binding in the inner Listview does not display. I can't seem to get to the second level of data.

The navigation path should be something like Car.Carcollection(Item).Carcollection but I cant do that in XAML

Comment: I have updated my answer, the code does work, once I fix the several typos

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, the issue must lie somewhere else in my project.

Comment: Oh my...
I'm sorry to have taken up your time.
The issue was that I didn't set the collection property in the object constructor.
It never got populated in the collection in the first place.
Big Facepalm...

Comment: No problem at all Hidde, glad it works now :-). Happy coding!